# What's the best way to convert iPad app to handle both view modes?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.6, landscape-portrait

I have an existing iPad app (XCode 4.6, iOS 6.2, ARC and Storyboards).  It is currently in the App Store in Portrait mode only; I have had several requests for landscape mode.  Unfortunately, all of the lines, etc are drawn using CG methods, controlled mathematically.  This is what it looks like in portrait mode:

[image: portrait mode]

and this is what it looks like in landscape mode:

[image: landscape mode]

My question is:  where can I find some good docs that will give me the basic steps I need to convert this app for both modes, knowing that the drawing is controlled mathematically?

Comment: This looks like the perfect place to use a CollectionView, why are you using CG to draw this?

Comment: CG was the only way I could figure out how to get the correct number of lines, both for rows and columns.  In addition, the whole bottom view must scroll like Excel, where the left column and top row move with the data.

Comment: Try follow this tutorial, if you want, and you could maybe apply it to your case here. It will ensure your codebase will be a lot easier to maintain. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Comment: Can the left column and top row be made so it follows the scroll?  (ie "frozen" like in spreadsheets)

Comment: sure why not, the left column can be the section header and the top can be a separate collection view. you can them simply resize the views in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` which will handle the repositioning of the cells automatically.

Comment: Wow!  Let me check out the tutorial URL you gave me... I'll get back to you.

Comment: Definetively a UICollectionView is a good way to go. However for a custom view I recommend using relative coordinates and not absolute as with relative the view sclaes to every size and orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is controlled mathematically, the best way is to refer all coordinates to the dimensions of the parent view, specifically to the property self.view.bounds that changes with the rotation of the device.

Then you have to redraw the interface when the orientation has been changed. A good way to do it is inside the method:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

If did some custom views in the past with CG methods and the best way is to refer everything to the bounds. In that way when you change the screen size, either by rotating or by using it on the iPhone it works without modifications.

**update**
Imagine that you have a point at (76.8, 512.0) this is precisely in an iPad and portrait orientation, a 10% of the width and a 50% of the height.
So for every pair of coordinates instead of using them with absolute numbers you have to replace them by fractions of the dimensions of the parent view:

```
// old drawing method
CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(76.8, 512.0);

// new drawing method
CGFloat W = self.view.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat H = self.view.bounds.size.height; 
CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(0.1 * W, 0.5 * H)  // 76.8 = 0.1 * 768; 512 = 0.5 * 1024
```

In this second case; when you change the orientation so will the bounds change and the coordinate will get new values, but the proprotion will be the same as in the other orientation, 10% in horizontal and 50% in vertical.

You get the idea.

Comment: Juan: can you point me to some docs that will give me some guidance on drawing using what you have described?  (I've looked but apparently don't have the search terms worded correctly)

Comment: Yep, I get the idea... thank you so much... I'm going to give it a go and see how it goes... I'll get back to you...

Comment: Happy to help you!. BTW what is the name of your app?

Comment: @spokane-dude did my answer help you? What have you decided to do?

Comment: I wanted to leave the question open until I could check it out further, specifically the mathematical parts, if that's ok with you... didn't forget you... :D

Comment: @spokane-dude I am here to help feel free to ask more questions. I like your app and can help you.